# Migrate a Drupal Site with AWS

Tags: php, drupal, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, open-atrium

I'm trying to migrate a open atrium (based on drupal) site to a new AWS EC2 instance.
I was following the steps of migrating a site from http://drupal.org. I'm sure that the `settings.php` and new database is configured right. But when I try to open the new site it always shows a blank page. Can anyone help me identify the problem?

Ps, I did try a fresh install and it works fine.

Comment: Which HTTP server are you running?

Comment: It runs Apache on the http server.

Comment: What is showing in your error logs?

Comment: The error log shows: Fatal error: Call to undefined function user_access() in /var/www/html/oa_test/includes/theme.inc on line 1804

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the security groups are defined correctly for your EC2 instance (for example, that port 80 is open...).

If you're using different instances for apache and the database - make sure the security groups are also configured properly for those.

Also, try and use an amazon instance of the same distro as you're using before migrating (e.g. CentOS, Ubuntu, ...), and make sure the settings.php and new database are configured as they should.

Alternatively - you can try something like http://www.ravellosystems.com - it will let you use VMs which are 100% identical to the ones you're migrating from, or even just upload your current VMs.

-- Full disclosure - I work for Ravello Systems.